# How to calculate standard error and CI to plot in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I am first calculating the percentage of respondents across different demographics who graduated from high school, based on their program status. This code gets me those percents:

```
d_perc <- d %>% 
  group_by(group, levels, program_cat, highschool) %>% 
  summarize(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(percent = n/sum(n)*100) %>% 
  select(-n)
```

Next, I want to additionally calculate error term around these perents. What is the best way to then calculate the SEs and corresponding 95% CI? (My ultimately goal is to then use `geom_point()` and `geom_errorbar` to plot these together, though I already have code to do this.)

I tried something like:

```
d_perc$se <- sqrt(d_perc$percent*(1-d_perc$percent)/d_perc$percent)
```

Which would then be followed by something like `+ and - 1.96*d_perc$se` to get the upper and lower estimate. However, when I try the above, I just get a series of NaNs for the se column.

Data here (sorry for the large data; I used head(100) to get somewhat more realistic percents by group):

```
d_perc <- structure(list(highschool= structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("no", 
"yes"), class = "factor"), program_cat = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), levels = c("0", "1", "2"), class = "factor"), group = c("gender", 
"race", "cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", "race", 
"cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", 
"gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", 
"race", "cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", "race", 
"cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", 
"gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", 
"race", "cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", "race", 
"cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", 
"gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", 
"race", "cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", "race", 
"cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", 
"gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", 
"race", "cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", "race", 
"cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", "gender", "race", "cohort", 
"gender"), levels = structure(c(1L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 
6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 
1L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 
3L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 
6L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 
1L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 
3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 2L), levels = c("Female", 
"Male", "Black", "Hispanic", "White", "CohortA", "CohortB"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You are calculating the standard error of a proportion. However, `percent` is not a proportion since you multiplied it by 100. So in your formula when you do `1-percent` you get negative numbers that you are then trying to take the square root of, resulting in `NaN`.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to compute the standard error of a proportion the formula is `sqrt(p * q / n)` where `q` is 1 - p. Notice you divide by `n` not `p` (in your example you are dividing by `p`). The way you have it written now the `d_perc$percent` will just cancel and you will be left with `sqrt(1-d_perc$percent)`.

Comment: Generally, it might be better to ask if your data are structured in a way that is giving you what you want. Yes, your code will generate some output for those grouping variables. However, it looks like you might consider pivoting your `group` and `levels` columns into a wider format before trying to make this computation. To do this though, it looks like there might be some ID column that is not present in your data that will uniquely identify the individual from a given race, gender, and cohort.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, your two variables `group` and `levels` actually represent three different variables and should be pivoted into wide format. I assume that every three rows represent a single observation of these variables.

To get upper and lower confidence intervals on a proportion, the simplest method is probably just to use `prop.test` so you get the correct binomial confidence intervals with continuity correction.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d_perc <- d %>% 
  mutate(id = (seq(nrow(.)) - 1) %/% 3) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = levels, 
              id_cols = c(id, program_cat, highschool)) %>%
  group_by(program_cat, gender, race, cohort) %>% 
  mutate(lower = prop.test(table(highschool))$conf[1],
         upper = prop.test(table(highschool))$conf[2],
         prop  = prop.test(table(highschool))$est) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.))
```

This gives us a data frame suitable for plotting:

```r
d_perc
#> # A tibble: 33 x 9
#>       id program_cat highschool gender race     cohort   lower upper  prop
#>    <dbl> <fct>       <fct>      <fct>  <fct>    <fct>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     0 1           no         Female Black    CohortB 0.310  1     1    
#>  2     1 1           no         Male   White    CohortB 0.0546 1     1    
#>  3     2 0           no         Female Black    CohortA 0.299  0.989 0.8  
#>  4     3 1           no         Male   Hispanic CohortA 0.0546 1     1    
#>  5     4 0           yes        Female White    CohortB 0      0.945 0    
#>  6     5 1           no         Female Black    CohortB 0.310  1     1    
#>  7     6 1           no         Female Black    CohortA 0.198  1     1    
#>  8     7 0           no         Female Black    CohortA 0.299  0.989 0.8  
#>  9     8 0           no         Female Black    CohortB 0.299  0.989 0.8  
#> 10     9 0           yes        Female White    CohortA 0.0177 0.875 0.333
#> # i 23 more rows
#> # i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

And we can use ggplot like this:

```r
ggplot(d_perc, aes(cohort, prop, color = program_cat)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.6)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), size = 3) +
  facet_grid(gender~race, switch = "y") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Note that because of the small sample size per category, there are insufficient data points to create realistic confidence intervals, and some are 100% or 0% which looks a bit odd - this is a limitation of the small example data set rather than the method.